# C# Application won't close

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program that uses a char value to determine which string to write. Currently I have (with both cPlant and sSql declared earlier)

```
if (cPlant == 'B')
{
    sSql = "somestring1";
}
else if (cPlant == 'D')
{
    sSql = "somestring2";
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error!");
    Application.Exit();
    MessageBox.Show("Shouldn't see this!");
}
```

Shouldn't `Application.Exit();` kill the program?

Comment: We'd need to see more of the code before this to make an accurate determination on our own. Have you tried printing the value of `cPlant` before this `if` block, to make sure the values are correct and the code path is actually being executed?

Comment: You can use Exceptions for this scenario, and you can provide a message to user, e.g. "The char is incorrect". The program will be closed automatically.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda, do you mean *closed due to unhandled exception* ? Bad idea.

Comment: The code path is being executed because if cPlant == D or B then it writes the string and the application runs smoothly. 

Before this was 

if (sMachNum.StartsWith("Q"))
      cPlant = 'C';
    else if (sMachNum.StartsWith("W"))
      cPlant = 'B';
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Error!");
    }

Comment: @Sinatr, why "closed due to unhadled exception" is worse than "the program closed I do not know why"?

Comment: @AlexSikilinda proper software has proper error handling. Yes, you can have unhandled exception crash due to something *unexpected*. But using unhandled exception to control program flow (in this case - to exit program) is [bad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264997.aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr, agree, except the point that good software should display some kind of validation message, but not close itself. Closing the app in most cases is unexpected situation (i.e. exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Application.Exit();
> ```

All that does is post a message to the message pump requesting the application closes (much like the user clicking the close icon).

All the normal exit code (eg. form's implementing [`OnClosing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosing.aspx)) will run after the caller returns so the message pump can process outstanding messages.

Of course something in all the code that runs could cancel the closure…

Comment: Note, to do anything non-trivial in WinForms you need to be aware of the underlying (Win32) mechanisms it builds on. Hence talk of the message pump.

Answer (score -2):

You can also try:

```
this.close();
```

Comment: Console application doesn't instantiate anything to have `this`.

Comment: I have an option for a file menu with an "Exit" button. I use this.Close(); there and the program terminates, but for some reason that code doesn't work here